# Skeleton text is not showing when observable is empty

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a list of user which I get the data from an api. So of course this data is not there immediately so I want to indicate the loading with an skeleton text until the data is actually available. I actually already doing the same with when I search so there it shows the skeleton text when im searching. But somehow it doesn't work for the first data conception. When I open the page the screen is just white until there is data.

It also works when Im searching and enter something that is no user I get a skeleton text until I enter a valid username so I don't get why it doesn't work for the first data conception since the list is also empty then!?

Here is my code:

#### page.html

```
  <ion-list id="skeleton" *ngIf="searching || (userList | async) == 0">
    <ion-item lines="none" *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">
      <ion-avatar>
        <ion-skeleton-text animated></ion-skeleton-text>
      </ion-avatar>
        <ion-label text-wrap>
          <h2>
              <ion-skeleton-text animated style="width: 60%"></ion-skeleton-text>
            </h2>
            <p>
                <ion-skeleton-text animated style="width: 40%"></ion-skeleton-text>
            </p>

        </ion-label> 
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-virtual-scroll [items]="(userList | async)" approxItemHeight="50px" approxItemWidth="300px" class="pad" mode="ios">

        <ion-item *virtualItem="let user; let i = index">
     <ion-avatar  class="user-image"  slot="start" >
            <ion-img src="assets/22.jpeg"> </ion-img>
     </ion-avatar>
        <ion-label text-wrap>
            <h2 class="title">{{user.username}}</h2>
          </ion-label>
      </ion-item>

  </ion-virtual-scroll>
```

#### page.ts

```
 public searchTerm: string = "";
  userList: Observable<any>;
  friendsList: Observable<any>;
  offset = 0;
  searching = false;
...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllUsers();   // get the users
}



  getAllUsers() {
    this.searching = true;
    this.userList = this.userService.getList() // initials 12 users
    .pipe(map(response => response.results));
    this.searching = false;
  }


  filterUsers(searchTerm) {
    this.searching = true;
    this.getAllUsers();
    return this.userList.pipe(
      map(res => {
        const result = res.filter(user => {
          return user.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1; });
        this.searching = false;
        console.log(result);
        return result;
          })
          );
        }

  searchList() {
    this.userList = this.filterUsers(this.searchTerm);
    console.log(this.searchTerm);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ngIf` condition for the skeleton is expecting `searching` to equal true or the `async` value evaluates to `0`.

Your component initialized the `searching` value to false and then calls `getAllUsers()`

So for you to show the skeleton, `getAllUsers` should set `searching` to `true`.

```js
getAllUsers() {
  this.searching = true;
  //...

}
```

Once the `async` call returns, you should set `searching` back to `false`

**Edit**

The `getAllUsers` method is immediately setting `this.searching` to false.

```
getAllUsers() {
  this.searching = true;
  this.userList = this.userService.getList() // initials 12 users
    .pipe(map(response => response.results));
  this.searching = false;
}
```

Change to:

```
getAllUsers() {
  this.searching = true;
  this.userList = this.userService.getList() // initials 12 users
    .pipe(
      map(response => response.results),
      tap(_ => this.searching = false)
    );
}
```

Comment: so I actually tried it. But I still don't see the skeleton text. I think it actually should work since I don't do the `this.searching = false;` again I just get an endless skeleton text. But why don't I get the animation between starting the page and getting the data. I think it actually should be enough time since I stopped the time from initiating the page and displaying the data which is about 0.8 seconds. Could it be because the animation takes so delay? I updated my answer with your proposition which is yet not working.

Comment: I suppose the problem could also be that the data in very fast in the observable (too fast to show skeleton text) but it takes some time to display so I want to ask if there is some way to show the text as long nothing is displayed on screen

Comment: @ColinRagnarök try initializing the `searching` variable with true instead of false

Comment: sadly this does work neither:( Is there any other way for doing this?

Comment: @ColinRagnarök check the edit .. spotted another issue

Comment: @ C_Ogoo thank you. It worked to that extent that I have the animation before. Between the animation and the displaying of the data I still get for like some milliseconds a white screen before the data displays. Is this normal or is there smth. one can make to immediately change from displaying the skeleton animation to the real data?

Comment: If you can reproduce this on stackblitz, I'll love to assist you @ColinRagnarök